# How to set the book image with the background of bookshelf using android?

Tags: android, image, background

I want to display the each book front image with the background of bookshelf image in android program?

Background Image----> Bookshelf image
Foreground image------>Books Front page image

Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/iphone" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Show us your xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/iphone" >

</LinearLayout>

Comment: iphone is the background image like bookshelf image of iphone...how to display the front page book image here

Comment: @rajesh If you want to provide more information (eg, the xml code you posted in the comment), you should do so in the question itself. not in comments, not as an answer. You'll notice that there is an edit link under your question. Use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `Relative Layout` instead. Then use `Image View` or `Image Button` and set the background of those `Image Views` or `Image Buttons` to the cover page of the book. With `Relative Layouts`, you can drag items with the click of your mouse and place them wherever you want on your layout. Use this to your advantage to place those `Image Views` or `Image Buttons` wherever you want and then set the individual backgrounds of the book covers.

**EDIT :** ***Code Addition :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/iphone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Perhaps something like this. But there will be few things that you'll need to change such as `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"` . I added `ic_launcher` lazily. So, you'll have to replace it with your book covers. Another thing you might have to change is re-positioning of `Image Views`. That's it I guess. Hope this helps.

Comment: i need that xml code.please can u show the relative layout code

Comment: post your image that you deleted.

Comment: u assume that bookshelf as a background image and book front page image as a foreground image.how to apply in xml file

Comment: thats ok.how to use these xml file in android activity

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [Gridview](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-simple-gridview-example.html) and place the shelf image to the background property of gridview.

Adjust the items inside the grids so that it appears to be over self rack.

Comment: I run the code.but the same image has displayed in all grid view.i want to display different book image and also i want to display the background image is like bookshelf.here background image is dark.

Comment: i put a background image in linear layout.now background image is working

Comment: set the background property of Gridview with shelf image

Comment: Background image is ok.Now the problem is the same book image is appear in all row and column in grid view.i want to show different book image

Comment: how to set the background property?

Comment: <GridView android:id="@+id/GridView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="10dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

  android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/bookshelf"/>

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the tick mark if you find it working.

Comment: Background image is ok.but the same book image is appear in all row and column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6456/discussion-between-jana-and-rajesh)